# Macro to replace values within a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large amount of data (approx 60 columns and 60,000 rows) formatted as a table in Excel. I'm looking to use a macro to replace all the values greater than 1 which reside in a column titled 'Salary' in the table with a value of '2'. the table is dynamic so I need to reference the replace to the  Tables column name rather than a column range like D:D.

**Update:**
I have put together the following code but cannot get it to work when i use What:=">0" however it will work if what="5". What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub FindReplace3()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(61).DataBodyRange.Replace _
 What:=">0", replacement:="7", _
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro for starters? Or looked up ListObject and ListColumn? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumn.databodyrange, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumn,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject

Comment: For a good start have a look at [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables). Try something and come back if you got stuck or errors and [edit] your question to show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this is your first post on Stackoverflow, so, welcome.

I also see you have been marked down for your question which can be disheartening as a first introduction the the site.

On SO there is an expectation that you will have researched and tried a number of things first and posted that information with the question.

You are very close, but your code is failing because you are searching for a literal string ">0" (What:=">0").  >0 obviously does not exist as a literal string.

The built in replace function limits the find to a literal string.  Therefore I would use this approach:

```
Sub replaceTest()

    Dim dblCnt As Double
    dblCnt = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count
            If Range("Table1[Salary]")(i) > 1 Then
                Range("Table1[Salary]")(i) = "2"
                dblCnt = dblCnt + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

MsgBox "Finished replacing " & CStr(dblCnt) & " items", vbOKOnly, "Complete"

End Sub
```

FYI, your code sample was referencing Column 61, but you said the column was called 'Salary'. You can reference the column name by changing your sample from:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(61).DataBodyRange.Replace _
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Salary").DataBodyRange.Replace _
```

I have added another code section below and credit must go to @Slai  His approach using the 'Evaluate' function is instantaneous compared to my original answer:

```
Sub replaceTest001()

    Dim StartTime As Date
    StartTime = Now()

    Dim dblCnt As Double
    dblCnt = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        [Table1[Salary]] = [if(Table1[Salary] > 1, 2, Table1[Salary])]
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Finished updating " & CStr(dblCnt) & " items" & vbCrLf & _
    "Time taken: " & Format((Now() - StartTime), "hh:mm:ss"), vbOKOnly, "Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, and apologies if it appears that I have not researched this enough.  I'm not a programmer/coder so this is quite new to me. The tip regarding referencing the table column name that is great, however i still couldn't get the code you wrote above to work. I am getting "Run-time error 1004 Method Range of Object _Global failed"

Comment: It sounds like the code does not know what sheet you are referencing.  I have modified the sample and wrapped it with a "With, End With".  Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes it worked (Thank You) but... it took more than 1 hour to complete (I'd been CTRL-Breaking for the past 2 days after 20-30 mins believing the application had hung).  Is there any way to speed this up with more efficient code? my PC is Intel i7-4510U CPU, 12GB RAM, 500MB SSD HD. The excel file is rather large at 17MB having 9 worksheets (total of 110 columns and 53,200 rows) the largest worksheet which is the one I want this code to run against is 78 columns and 32,000 rows.

Comment: Try putting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the `'With'` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after the `'End with'`

Comment: The With statements in your code samples don't do anything without `.` (for example `If .Range`). Also, Excel Table names and structured references are global to the whole workbook and don't need sheet name. As a side note, [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function) can be used instead of `Now()` for better precision.

Comment: @Slai, thanks for the information.  I had left the 'With' in as I was originally looping through all sheets.  I can see now it is superfluous.  I was using Now() instead of Timer to keep it all as dates rather than introducing a double.  I was only interested in precision to the nearest 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

[Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) can be used to replace all at once :

```
[Table1[Salary]] = [if(Table1[Salary] > 1, 2, Table1[Salary])]
```